# Save all meta tags name and value to an object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to read all the meta tags on a specific page and store each meta name and content values in a datalayer array that will be used for Google Tag Manager.

I want to fetch all the meta tags then I want to be able to push each value in the array accordingly.

I have the following code but I don't think it is the best way to do it if I have like 20-30 meta tags.I hope someone can help me improve this code!!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> test metas</title>
    <meta name="ABC" content="dummy"/>
    <meta name="DEF" content="dummy"/>
    <meta name="JHK" content="dummy"/>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function GTMMeta(name) { 
   var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
   for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
      if (metas[i].getAttribute('name') == name) { 
         return metas[i].getAttribute('content'); 
      } 
   } 
    return '';
} 

  dataLayer = [{}];

if (GTMMeta('ABC') !=''){
    dataLayer.push({'cmsName': GTMMeta('ABC')})
 }; 
if (GTMMeta('DEF') !=''){
  dataLayer.push({'transactionTotal': GTMMeta('DEF')});
}  

if (GTMMeta('JHK') !=''){
  dataLayer.push({'market': GTMMeta('JHK')});
}  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not the best way to do it, but it won't really matter unless you've got hundreds of tags.  You could at least save the return values when you check to see if a tag is present, instead of calling the function (and searching) twice.

Comment: @Pointy: Thank you so much. Considering that I will have about 30 metas on each page and I will need this snippet on 6-8 pages, then it will be very handy if there is a better way to write the metas in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save having to look through each `<meta>` every time, one way could be to put all the name/content pairs into an *Object*.

```
var metaObj = {}, m = document.head.getElementsByTagName('meta'), i = m.length;
while (i--) { // looping down will result in the same behaviour as stopping @ 1st
    metaObj[m[i].name] = m[i].content;
}
```

and then take what you want directly from your object

```
if (metaObj['ABC']) {
    dataLayer.push({'cmsName': metaObj['ABC']});
}
```

---

You could automate these too, by looping over a second *Object*, similar to that suggested by [Manishearth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14923268/1615483)

```
var metaInterest = {'ABC':'cmsName','DEF':'transactionTotal', 'JHK':'market'}, o;
for (i in metaInterest)
    if (metaInterest.hasOwnProperty(i) && metaObj[i])
        o = {}, o[metaInterest[i]] = metaObj[i], dataLayer.push(o);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, it is much better than the orginal code. I wonder however how I can pass different variables that will have different types such as numeric, string and arrays, as explained here. [link]https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/reference Let's assume that I want to add conversionAttributes in the dataLayer, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: This sounds like how do I convert "_String_ to _X_". It depends on what you want to end up with, lots of example around.

Comment: Thanks again, your answer is appreciated. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe form the array directly?

```
dataLayer = [];
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
   d={}
   d[metas[i].getAttribute('name')]=metas[i].getAttribute('content')
   datalayer.push(d)
}
```

If you want the array to have some aliases instead of the names(and only fetch for those aliases), then use:

```
aliases={'ABC':'cmsName','DEF':'transactionTotal', 'JHK':'market'}
dataLayer = [];
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
   d={}
   d[aliases[metas[i].getAttribute('name')]]=metas[i].getAttribute('content')
   aliases[metas[i].getAttribute('name')] && datalayer.push(d)
}
```

A side note: It's not necessary to have `dataLayer=[{}]`, `dataLayer=[]` is sufficient.

Comment: You still have `SyntaxError`s (both blocks); see simplified example of error in following: `({document['title']: 'foo'})`

Comment: @Manishearth: Thank you so much. You have been so helpful and your answer was excellent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's plenty of small tweaks you could do to this code to improve performance, but 20-30 tags is *not* a lot.  You could use `.content` on `metas[i]` instead of `.getAttribute` but it's going to be micro optimizations especially for processing only 20-30 items.

The best place to check for improvement in performance is http://jsperf.com